# On the sine transform and approximants defined from the Möbius function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-transform, mobius-function

I've written the Fourier sine transform $\mathcal{F}_s(f)(\nu)$ of a function $f(x)$ (see its definition from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms)) using the Proposition 1 of [1], the Prime Number Theorem, the change of variable $x=\nu t$ and integration.

For a large integer $N>1$, I define the approximants $$\mathcal{A}_N(f)(\nu):=-\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n}  \left\{ n\nu t \right\} \right)f(t)dt\tag{1}$$
where thus $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, and $  \left\{ x \right\} $ is the fractional part function; and being $$g(\nu):=\mathcal{F}_s(f)(\nu)$$ the Fourier sine transform of the function $f(x)$.

You can read the definition of the Möbius function from some free available  online encyclopedia.

> **Question.** In this situation I would like to know what kind of convergence can I presume for the limit $$\mathcal{A}_N(f)(\nu)\to g(\nu)\tag{2}$$ as $N\to\infty$. Alternatively/additionally quantify $$|\mathcal{A}_N(f)(\nu)-g(\nu)|\tag{3}$$ as $N\to\infty$. **Many thanks.**

### References:

You can read next reference from $\mathcal{The}$ EUROPEAN DIGITAL MATHEMATICS LIBRARY.

[1] S. Segal, *On an identity between infinite series of arithmetic functions*, Acta Arithmetica (1976), Volume: 28, Issue: 4, pp. 345-348.

Comment: If my question has no mathematical meaning, or my definiton of approximants is equivalent to some construction that was in the literature, please add a comment. Many thanks all users.

Comment: Impossible to understand for most people, make more efforts, read the books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP meant that from the Fourier series 
$$S(x) = -\pi (x-\lfloor x \rfloor) = -\frac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{ n}$$
And $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0$ (equivalent to the PNT)

We get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} S(nx) = \sin(2 \pi x)$$
The convergence being at least in $L^2([0,1])$.

Thus for any nice enough function $f$
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(2 \pi x)dx = \lim_{N \to \infty}  \int_0^\infty (\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} S(nx)) f(x)dx \tag{1}$$
Indeed, the set for which $(1)$ is true encodes the **Riemann hypothesis**.

Taking $f(x) =  x^{-\sigma-1}$, as $\int_0^\infty S(x) x^{-s-1}dx = \frac{\pi}{s} \zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s) \in (0,1)$ we see that
$$\int_0^\infty (\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} S(nx)) x^{-\sigma-1}dx = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \int_0^\infty  S(nx) x^{-\sigma-1}dx$$
$$ = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \int_0^\infty  S(y) (y/n)^{-\sigma-1}d(y/n)= \frac{\pi}{s} \zeta(s) \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n) n^{\sigma-1}$$
Thus 
$\int_0^\infty x^{-s-1} \sin(2 \pi x)dx = \lim_{N \to \infty}  \int_0^\infty (\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} S(nx)) x^{-\sigma-1}dx $
iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) n^{\sigma-1}$ converges (to $\frac{1}{\zeta(1-\sigma)}$) iff $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros for $\Re(s)\ge 1-\sigma$.

This is often mentioned as the functional analysis [criteria](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_de_la_fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#Crit.C3.A8res_.C3.A9quivalents_.C3.A0_l.27hypoth.C3.A8se_de_Riemann) for the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: I am going to study your answer. Merci.

Comment: @user243301 Sur MSE, remercier c'est étudier les réponses et poster des commentaires qui montrent que tu as appris des choses...

Comment: (1/2) Comment allez vous? Truly your answer is very nice and I hope that it obtain more upvotes. These months I wanted to study a (different) question about Nymann-Beurling's approach to the RH, but now the summer time is ending and I would like to know if my idea is good. The idea is try to combine real or complex theories of interpolation of Banach spaces, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space) with the definition of the Möbius function (as you see in my posts by means of small artifices).

Comment: (2/2 ) Thus try to exploit the shape of the zero free region in Nyman-Beurling approach, the definitions of functionals, methods of interpolation of spaces and operators with the definition or formulas for the Möbius/Mertens function. In some cases of this theory one can interpolate and extrapolate spaces in different situations. Do you think that it is interesting? Many thanks.

Comment: @user243301 I don't see what you mean. Formulas ? And to see if an approach to the RH has any chance to succeed, you need to look at those functions close to $\zeta(s)$ for which the RH fails.

Comment: I can't provide to you a precise idea. There are several methods to interpolate (Banach) spaces using interpolation methods associated to polygons. And I don't know if it is possible to combine such methods to deduce some useful in this situation. But as I as saying I can't provide to you a precise idea, thus don't worry about it, and many thanks @reuns

Comment: @user243301 What are you talking about ? In maths we use formulas.. The Banach space $B$ with norm $\|f\|_B= \|f\|_{L^1}+\|f\|_{L^2} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|dx+(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2dx)^{1/2}$ is called $L^1 \cap L^2$. Note setting $\|f\|_B = a\|f\|_{L^1}+b\|f\|_{L^2}$ with $a > 0,b > 0$ doesn't change the obtained Banach space. Following the same idea, the [interpolation space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space#The_setting_of_interpolation) of $L^1,L^2$ is $\|g\|_{L_1+L_2} = \inf_h \|h\|_{L^1}+ \|g-h\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your comment but as I said to you, currently I am not able to tell you the idea that I am looking for, because I can not yet specified it.